# Ajax Laravel pasar parametros y recibir la respuesta

Tags: laravel, ajax

Hola buenas me gustaria pasarle a mi funcion del controlador 2 paramatetros para hacer una consulta y me devuelva el valor de la misma, pero no consigo como hacerlo 
esta es mi llamada ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "precio",
    data: {tabla, nombre},
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function (response)
    {   
        resultado = response;   
    }
});
```

y esta es la funcion que tiene que recoger los parametros y hacer la consulta

```
   public function precio(request $request){

    $tabla = $request->tabla;
    $nombre = $request->nombre;

   if ($tabla == "bebidas"){
        $precio = Bebida::where('precio', $nombre)->get();
    } elseif ( $tabla == "comidas"){
        $precio = Comida::where('precio', $nombre)->get();
    } else {
        $precio = Postres::where('postres')->where('precio',  $nombre)->get();
    }

    return view('home', compact('precio'));
}
```

Y luego supongo que con el response ya obtengo el precio. Tampoco se si la consulta es la correcta para obtener el precio de nombre que le paso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la llamada ajax debes pasar los datos como pares `clave: valor`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "precio",
    data: {tabla: tabla, nombre: nombre},
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function (response)
    {   
        // ...   
    }
});
```

Y en el controlador obtienes los datos de las claves. Luego retorna los datos, no una vista:

```
public function precio(Request $request)
{
    // aquí ->tabla y ->nombre son las claves tabla:... y nombre:... 
    $tabla = $request->tabla;
    $nombre = $request->nombre;

    if ($tabla == "bebidas"){
        $precio = Bebida::where('precio', $nombre)->get();
    } elseif ( $tabla == "comidas"){
        $precio = Comida::where('precio', $nombre)->get();
    } else {
        $precio = Postres::where('precio',  $nombre)->get();
    }
    // El método json establecerá automáticamente el encabezado 'Content-Type' en 'application/json', así como también convertirá el array dado a JSON
    return response()->json(['data' => $precio]);
}
```

Finalmente, en la función success de ajax manejas la respuesta como tu quieras:

```
    success : function (response)
    {   
        // puedes hacer un console.log(response); para ver como está estructurada la respuesta 
        // los datos deberían estar dentro de response.data 
        // haz algo con los datos aquí  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás pasando mal los parámetros de [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Tenés que pasar algo así:

```
data: {nombre1: valor1, nombre2: valor2},
```

`nombre` es el nombre del campo con el que vas a acceder desde `$request` y `valor` obviamente el valor del campo. El valor puede ser un string, pero entiendo que en tu caso estás pasando una variable.

```
data: {tabla: tabla, nombre: nombre},
```